# Userform VBA Code For Command Button to run a sub when a textbox changes

Tags: excel, vba

So the first 9 lines where given to me in a forum I can't remember where. But I built on that and now I would like to use a command button to re-calculate if the use changes a variable listed in this sub.

```
Private Sub txtWorked_Exit(ByVal Cancel As     MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
11 Dim OTRate       As Double
  OTRate = Me.txtHourlyRate * 1.5
If Me.txtWorked > 40 Then
  Me.txtBasePay.Value = Format(Me.txtHourlyRate.Value * 40, "$#,##0.00")
  Me.txtOvertime = Format((Me.txtWorked - 40) * OTRate, "$#,##0.00")
Else
  Me.txtOvertime.Value = "0"
  Me.txtBasePay.Value = Format(Me.txtHourlyRate.Value *    Me.txtWorked.Value, "$#,##0.00")
End If
Dim Gross, W2, MASSTax, FICA, Medi, Total, Depends, Feds As Double
  Gross = CDbl(txtBonus.Value) + CDbl(txtBasePay.Value) +       CDbl(txtOvertime.Value)
  W2 = txtClaim * 19
  Me.txtGrossPay.Value = Format(Gross, "$#,##0.00")
  FICA = Gross * 0.062
  Me.txtFICA.Value = Format(FICA, "$#,##0.00")
  Medi = Gross * 0.0145
  Me.txtMedicare.Value = Format(Medi, "$#,##0.00")
  MASSTax = (Gross - (FICA + Medi) - (W2 + 66)) * 0.0545
If chkMassTax = True Then
   Me.txtMATax.Value = Format(MASSTax, "$#,##0.00")
Else: Me.txtMATax.Value = "0.00"
End If
If Me.txtClaim.Value = 1 Then
   Depends = 76.8

ElseIf Me.txtClaim.Value = 2 Then
   Depends = 153.8

ElseIf Me.txtClaim.Value = 3 Then
   Depends = 230.7
Else
   Depends = 0
End If
   If (Gross - Depends) < 765 Then
   Feds = ((((Gross - Depends) - 222) * 0.15) + 17.8)
  Me.txtFedIncome.Value = Format(Feds, "$#,##.00")
ElseIf (Gross - Depends) > 764 Then
   Feds = ((((Gross - Depends) - 764) * 0.25) + 99.1)
   Me.txtFedIncome.Value = Format(Feds, "$#,##.00")
Else:
   Feds = 0
End If
   Total = (txtMATax) + (FICA) + (Medi) + (txtAdditional) + (Feds)
   Me.txtTotal.Value = Format(Total, "$#,##0.00")
   Me.txtNetPay.Value = Format(Gross - Total, "$#,##0.00")

End Sub
 Private Sub cmdReCalculate_Click()
  'This where I would lke code to start the sub "txtWorked_Exit" to run again."
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is call the sub routine with the appropriate arguments.

```
Private Sub cmdReCalculate_Click()
   txtWorked_Exit true
End Sub
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but since `txtWorked_Exit` is most likely the `On Exit` event trigger of the `txtWorked` text box on the form, the OP would need to move the whole code into a stand alone sub for this to work?

Comment: Although separating the code into a stand alone sub would be a good best practice, it is not necessary.  The Cancel argument tells the sub if the same behavior is to follow as if the user actually exits the textbox.  I passed in a value of true because I am not sure what the desired overall effect is, but false could be passed if there is supposed to be no other behavior after the sub is ran.

Comment: @Scott Yes, the form will calculate all the code you see when the user exits the worked textbox.  I suppose I could stick all that code under the cmdReCalc button.....Just call the button Calculate

Comment: My problem is that if the user makes a mistake and or wants to change one of the variables that that sub has calculated the user would have to activate txtWorked and then exit to see the changes.  Hense the "Re"Calculate button.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions that didn't work I tried this.

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()
   Me.txtWorked.SetFocus
   Me.txtAdditional.SetFocus
End Sub
```

It basically made the Worked textbox active and by doing the same to another text box it effectively preformed an "_Exit" from txtWorked and thus re-ran the txtWorked_Exit Sub.